# Lebesgue measure of the graph of a function

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let $f: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ be any function.
Will the graph of f always have Lebesgue measure zero ?

1) I could prove that this is true if f is continuous.

2) I suspect it is true if f is measurable, but I'm not sure. 
(My idea was to use Fubini's theorem to integrate the indicator function of the graph, but I don't know if I'm using the theorem properly).

If 2) is incorrect, what would be a counterexample where the graph of f has positive measure ?

If 2) is correct, can we prove the existence of a non-measurable function whose graph has positive measure ?

Comment: More appropriate for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Note that if $f$ is non-measurable then the graph of $f$ is not a measurable set, so in this case you should probably ask if it has positive inner measure (or outer measure).

Comment: OK, I will post it there instead

Comment: Since it has now been posted to m.se (it's question 35606 there), I guess we can close it here. 

Comment: I posted an answer over at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/lebesgue-measure-of-the-graph-of-a-function. One can build a function using the axiom of choice, whose graph is not contained in any $G_\delta$ set with less than full measure. Thus, the graph has full outer measure. Meanwhile, the inner measure must always be zero, since there are uncountably many disjoint vertical translations.

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is a measurable function, then its graph is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R^{n+m}$.
By Fubini's theorem, the measure of the graph is 0.

Comment: (Hoping that someone will see this) why does that follow from Fubini?